# Can I use my own attributes for the Magento 1 to Magento 2 migration tool?

Tags: magento2, magento2-migration-tool

I am trying to migrate some information from Magento 1 to Magento 2. I have created all my attributes, sets and group in Magento 2 and would like to migrate my M1 products to M2.

I assumed that I would be able to do this with the Magento 1 to Magento 2 migration tool, but it keeps trying to clear down my data in Magento 2. Can I skip this? Is my approach of only wanting to migrate certain data even going to work?

Answer (score 0):

You didn't exactly need to create them as the migration tool can in many scenarios create the attribute sets etc. to match exactly, database to database.

It is fields added by extensions to the attributes table which complicate things (they need to be mapped or ignored) but values tend to carry over as is.

If you run the migration tool, after you ignore or map all the extension related fields (added to orders, customers, attribute definitions etc) you will find your product attributes sets have been migrated (additionally to the ones you created, though there might be a configuration to map it)

It takes quite a few tries (I'm still in the middle) but it gets there. It is attributes added to users, orders and other things than products which are the most complicated. Attributes you built yourself tend to carry over OK. (images need to be copied - just copying the folder over does it)

You have to dig in the xml configuration files - at least for me it's a bit of trial and error.

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately, once you've spent a couple of days creating all your attributes, options and attribute sets, the right answer is "oh, you didn't need to do that" :) So I've gone down my normal route of writing the migration myself. Much quicker and less hair being pulled out as I know exactly what it's doing. I'm sure the migration tool is great for the person who created it, but without more documentation I'm leaving it alone.